# how to handle swal alert popup in selenium using java....?

Tags: selenium, popup, sweetalert

how to handle sweet alert popup in selenium(java)
 -> click on submit button in popup then redirect to next page[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToAYa.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eA0Wt.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Check [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Copy > JS Path.. and then add ".click()"

```
document.querySelector("body > div.sweet-alert.showSweetAlert.visible > div.sa-button-container > div > button").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

As this is not a standard alert, I think you should be able to access the 'Accept' button by using the following xpath.

```
//div['sweet-alert showSweetAlert visible']//button[@class='confirm']
```